# Set a -U password from inside a kdb process

Tags: kdb

Is it possible to set a password file from inside a kdb process if it was not initialized with one? \u only seems to work if the process was started with a -U flag in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, has to be specified on startup. Then while running, `\u` will reload the file.

You could alternatively use [`.z.pw`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zpw-validate-user) to control access. This can be set at any time